# installing a wildcard Certificate on a subdomain running on ubuntu

Tags: apache2, ssl, certificates, owncloud-server, wildcards

i have tried for a full day in vain to install a wildcard Certificate on owncloud (which is a subdomain and running on obuntu 16.04 with apache2)

Any one who can help me here with concrete steps? Thanks in advance.

This is what i did:

I configured 000-default.conf like this;

(was 80 and changed it to 443)

servername http://IP-Address/owncloud
SSL Engine on
SSLcertificateFile            /path
SSLcertificateKeyFile         /path
SSLcertificateChainFile       /path

DocumentRoot /var/www/html

Answer (score 0):

Do not change  000-default.conf, but use default-ssl.conf, which should be there is you enabled ssl.
In that sample file default-ssl.conf you will find many SSL parameters.
ServerName is the name of your webserver for ssl usage (like: exmple.com).
Enable the site default-ssl. etc.